# WPF Cell Button Hide on certain condition

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

- I have data source which, getting bind to grid in WPF. Data source is
  array of students, with following fields
- Name, Grade

Grid have 3 columns

---

Name, Grade, Settings

Settings column contains simple button for settings as below

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Settings" Width="75"  CanUserResize="False">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                          <Button  Name="cSettings"   Click="cSettings_Click" Style="{DynamicResource EditSettingsButton}" Width="50" >
                          </Button>
                 </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Now, If **grade is equal to one** then only,Settings Button should get displayed.
Can I write condition in XAML itself ? i.e. Visibility of button should be on some condition ?

Tried below approach but not working

```
<DataTemplate>
        <Button  Name="cSettings"   Click="cSettings_Click" Style="{DynamicResource EditSettingsButton}" Width="50" >
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Grade}" Value="1">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                  </DataTrigger>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Grade}" Value="2">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                  </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try changing `<Style>` to `<Button.Style>`. Right now you are setting the `Button.Content` to the `Style` object, but you need to be setting `<Button.Style>` to the specified style instead

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `converter` instead. See this [link](http://www.wynapse.com/XAML/Converters/BoolToVisibilityConverter.aspx)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply, but it means, I should write code c# for it.
Is it not possible in XAML ?

Comment: Thanks..finally I have used Standard Way only !